# string somString = {"D", how to set?

Tags: c#, string

C#
It's possible to set to a variant this sentence `{"D"`, and receive precisely the same string. I try some variants, for sample:

```
1) "{""D""," = "End of expression expeted" error;  
2) @"{""D""," = "{\"D\","
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but dos batch files doesn't have data types, and thus strings are not usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the second suggestion is the one you want. The slashes in the output are displayed there by VS for clarity. The string is actually **{"D"**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
string S = "{\"D\",";
```

In other words, " can be escaped by `\`.